Graphic of the count values of a column that matches a correspondent value in another column PowerBI
i'm struggling to create a graphic of the sum values of a column that matches a correspondent value in another column in Power BI.
I have several columns with clustered values: let's use as example, columns A, B, and C. I want to create a graph displaying the count of values equal to 1 in columns B and C, separately. Additionally, I want to filter these counts based on the corresponding values in Column A, specifically when Column A equals 1.
this was an fail attempt to do it
i've tried in many ways, filtering values in the graph, using different graphics, but didn't manage to get a solution, i would really aprecciate some help!
this is a sample of the columns i'm working on:
Columns

It would be great if you can provide a set of sample data and the Measure you are trying with.
